# What AWS services/architecture is used as I have Front-End, Back-End & Database Application?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services

As I am new to AWS, so it will be really helpful for me if someone suggest me the correct strategy.
I have requirement in which I have to deploy Back-End Application with Node.js and Front-End Application in React.js which call endpoint of Node.js.

And the database is PostgresSQL.

So, as per my understanding below AWS service to be used for Back-End & Database: -

1). Node.js - Back-End Application: - To be deploy over EC2 instance

2). PostgresSQL - Database: - To be deploy over RDS Service

But I am not sure which service to be use for Front-End -- React.js, so that it can call an endpoint of Back-End Application deploy on EC2 instance?

Comment: AWS Amplify could make your life a bit easier if you're new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use EC2 for the front-end. With EC2 you get direct access to a server and you can configure it however you like.

But since a pure front-end application is just a bunch of HTML, Javascript and CSS files, you can also deploy it to Amazon S3 (+ an optional CDN for better performance and less cost). You might want to check articles like [this one](https://www.cloudthat.com/resources/blog/step-by-step-guide-to-deploy-reactjs-app-on-aws-s3).

Bonus: you might also want to check [AWS Amplify](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-react-app-amplify-graphql/) for these purposes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. This will really help in deciding further approach of my applications. Will first try deploying it over EC2 as it is dynamic front-end application and will also explore AWS Amplify and will check it feasibility.

Answer (score 1):

ANother option you have is you can deploy your client to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Elastic Beanstalk is a service for deploying and scaling web applications and services. Upload your code and Elastic Beanstalk automatically handles the deployment—from capacity provisioning, load balancing, and auto scaling to application health monitoring.This service hosts web apps.

For details, see  https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk.

Comment: So, now I have three options for Web Application deployment
1). EC2 Instance
2). AWS S3 Bucket
3). Elastic Beanstalk.

         My scenario is Front-End is calling an endpoint of Node.js application deploy over EC2 instance.
Endpoint logic is written using axios npm.
So, to achieve this scenario I am still not sure 
out of these three services which service is more suitable?

Comment: As wel you can deploy to containers using services like AWS Fargate. You need to read the documentation and once you learn more about the possible deployment solution, you have to determine which one best meets you business requirements. The community can tell you the possiblities, but its up to you to determine the best solution.